# Google Maps Api don't load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have home.php, on tag head load with jquery another page corpo_home.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Loadcorpo(P1){
        $("#corpo").load("corpo_home.php?sq="+elecodice[P1]+"&an="+eleanno[P1]);
    }
</script>
```

On `corpo_home.php` I declare api key and function to load map:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=>123456&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize(P2){
        var coordinate = P2.split(',')
        alert("before");
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate[0], coordinate[1]);
        alert("after");
        var mapOptions = {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: 17,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title:""
        });
    }
    });
</script>
```

When the page index.php load I see alert "before" but not "after".

Can you help me?

Comment: Check developers console.

Comment: Where are you calling your `initialize` function?

Answer (score 1):

I found many syntax errors:

1. After the split, there's no `;`.
2. For some reason you closed the function with `});` when only `}` is needed.
3. The `marker` variable closes right after `title:""` with `});` so the curly bracket after it shouldn't be there.

Other than that, I don't see why it's not working. Please show where you're calling `initialize();`

For now, use this code instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=>123456&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize(lat, lng){ // edited on first edit
    alert("before");

    var LatLng = { // edited on first edit
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
    };

    alert("after");

    var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);    

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map, 
        title: ""
    });
}
</script>
```

**- EDIT -**

Alright, so you call the function with this:

```
<img onload="javascript:initialize('<?php echo $row_record['pzcoordi'];?>');"  src="images/blank.gif"/>
```

First, I would use a `div` instead of an `img`, but if it works, that's ok. I see your approach to pass a parameter and then split it on JavaScript. Pretty genius. But I see you are passing the parameter as a string. This won't work because the API expects them to be integer.

To diagnose better, I would love to see how you built those next and previous buttons, since they work fine, but I will just move on with my guess.

I suggest that you pass 2 parameters, the `Lat` and `Lng` coordinates, and to achieve that, you need to `explode();` them in PHP:

```
<?php
    $array = explode(",", $row_record['pzcoordi']);
    $lat = $array[0];
    $lng = $array[1];
?>
<img onload="initialize(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $lng; ?>)"  src="images/blank.gif"/>
```

If this doesn't work for any reason, maybe you could wrap the parameters with single quotes to make them strings, but I wouldn't rely on that. And I know that `explode();` returns strings, but they will only be strings for HTML and PHP, JavaScript will take them as integers because they won't be wrapped with single quotes. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Roberta Please don't answer your own questions, comment on the answers like this. I can't comment on your question because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: I tried using div instead img but never working.

You're right about integers but also put fixed coordinates map load only the second time...

Comment: I made a small environment test to simplify web pages. Then I put map in the first program (home.php) and also the first time ( or when press F5 to refresh) work.
The problem is put map in program corpo_home.php called by jquery. Why? Grrrrrrrr

Comment: Hummm problem is only on Chrome and Explorer, Firefox it's ok.

Comment: @Roberta Let me explain (and let me know if you prefer Italian, I'm Italian-Argentine). The `map` variable in the JavaScript will give the map options to any element with the `id` `map_canvas`. The only thing you need to do is create a `<div>` tag with that `id`, then you can add a `class` for CSS and in your JavaScript, add `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` after the function. And by the way, **there is no need at all to use the key and function in another file**

Comment: @Roberta But anyway, that method won't work for you since you need to pass on the parameters for initialize... either way, I don't understand what you're trying to say about putting the map on `corpo_home.php`. I thought you would only use it to load the map and output it in `home.php`.

Comment: @Roberta May I see the entire source code of both files? I really have no idea what's going on with your algorithm. It just doesn't make sense at all to me.

Comment: @Roberta last tip, I don't know if you saw this correction, but remember to write `onload="initialize(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $lng; ?>)"` in the `<img>`. As you can see, I stripped out `javascript:` and the semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for syntax corrections.

I call inizialize() in this way:

```
<img onload="javascript:initialize('<?php echo $row_record['pzcoordi'];?>');"  src="images/blank.gif" />
```

The home.php have button previous and next, onclick corpo_home.php reload, read coordinates from database and show the maps.

The fist time map not load, if click on next button and then return back map load properly.